# Fetch email from Office365 using POP3 without fetching old emails

Tags: email, gmail, office365, pop3

So I recently decided that I wanted to receive all my emails to Gmail, since I really like the tabs. I went ahead and set up email fetching, using POP3, from my school's Office365 mail.

I don't know if these two are correlated but:

1. I am NOT getting new emails that come in the Office365 account.
2. Gmail is importing all of my old emails (so about 5 years of mail). Moreso, it imports them as unread emails.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I suggest you set up a forwarding rule in your O365 mailbox if you do not want all of the old mail. This will allow you to just copy new mails going forward.
2. POP does not keep item read/unread status. Each item is evaluated as read/unread by the client only.

Comment: So there are no "advanced" settings for O365 involving POP3 like the ones Gmail has-

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gmail's inbound POP settings, but numerous sources (couldn't find an RFC or anything) state that identifying read/unread status isn't part of the protocol.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/389297/dovecot-how-to-make-pop3-and-imap-treat-read-unread-status-independently-of-one --crosslink to Dovecot question on ServerFault.